# JQuery FileDrop.js How To Read Data Params in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, filedrop.js

Using ASP.NET MVC 5, I'm having trouble reading the param data I am sending from my filedrop jquery code into my controller.

Here is my .cshtml filedrop code:

[image]

And here is my Controller code, showing that param1 is being passed as null:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a variable that will hold that the value of attribute. like this

```
var idValue = $('id').val();
```

And then pass this variable to the data.

```
data: { params: idValue }
```